# React-Router: how to wait for an async action before route transition

Tags: reactjs, state, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

Is it possible to call an async redux action known as a `thunk` on a particular route and not perform the transition until the response has succeeded or failed?

**Use Case**

We need to load data from the server and fill a form with initial values. These initial values don't exist until the data is fetched from the server.

some syntax like this would be great:

```
<Route path="/myForm" component={App} async={dispatch(loadInitialFormValues(formId))}>
```

Comment: When is the expected route change happening? Is it from someone clicking on a link or a button? Or something else?

Comment: Well, any of those: button, programatically, page load etc.. all those cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**To answer the original question of preventing the transition to a new route until a response has succeeded or failed:**

Because you're using redux thunk you could have the success or failure in the action creator trigger the redirect. I don't know what your specific action / action creator looks like but something like this could work:

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

export function loadInitialFormValues(formId) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    // hit the API with some function and return a promise:
    loadInitialValuesReturnPromise(formId)
      .then(response => {
        // If request is good update state with fetched data
        dispatch({ type: UPDATE_FORM_STATE, payload: response });

        // - redirect to the your form
        browserHistory.push('/myForm');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // If request is bad...
        // do whatever you want here, or redirect
        browserHistory.push('/myForm')
      });
  }
}
```

**Follow up. Common pattern of loading data on entering a route / on componentWillMount of a component and displaying a spinner:**

From the redux docs on async actions http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

> - An action informing the reducers that the request began.
>
> The reducers may handle this action by toggling an isFetching flag in
>   the state. This way the UI knows it’s time to show a spinner.
>
> - An action informing the reducers that the request finished successfully.
>
> The reducers may handle this action by merging the new data into the
>   state they manage and resetting isFetching. The UI would hide the
>   spinner, and display the fetched data.
>
> - An action informing the reducers that the request failed.
>
> The reducers may handle this action by resetting isFetching.
>   Additionally, some reducers may want to store the error message so the
>   UI can display it.

I followed this general pattern below using your situation as a rough guideline. You do not have to use promises

```js
// action creator:
export function fetchFormData(formId) {
  return dispatch => {
    // an action to signal the beginning of your request
    // this is what eventually triggers the displaying of the spinner
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_FORM_DATA_REQUEST })

    // (axios is just a promise based HTTP library)
    axios.get(`/formdata/${formId}`)
      .then(formData => {
        // on successful fetch, update your state with the new form data
        // you can also turn these into their own action creators and dispatch the invoked function instead
        dispatch({ type: actions.FETCH_FORM_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: formData })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // on error, do whatever is best for your use case
        dispatch({ type: actions.FETCH_FORM_DATA_ERROR, payload: error })
      })
  }
}

// reducer

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  formData: {},
  error: {},
  fetching: false
}

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_FORM_DATA_REQUEST:
      // when dispatch the 'request' action, toggle fetching to true
      return Object.assign({}, state, { fetching: true })
    case FETCH_FORM_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        fetching: false,
        formData: action.payload
      })
    case FETCH_FORM_DATA_ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload
      })
  }
}

// route can look something like this to access the formId in the URL if you want
// I use this URL param in the component below but you can access this ID anyway you want:
<Route path="/myForm/:formId" component={SomeForm} />

// form component
class SomeForm extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // get formId from route params
    const formId = this.props.params.formId
    this.props.fetchFormData(formId)
  }

  // in render just check if the fetching process is happening to know when to display the spinner
  // this could also be abstracted out into another method and run like so: {this.showFormOrSpinner.call(this)}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="some-form">
        {this.props.fetching ? 
          <img src="./assets/spinner.gif" alt="loading spinner" /> :
          <FormComponent formData={this.props.formData} />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fetching: state.form.fetching,
    formData: state.form.formData,
    error: state.form.error
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchFormData })(SomeForm)
```

Comment: That seems like an anti-pattern. I was thinking all routes that match a pattern could trigger a reload of the state to keep the whole state tree updated automatically

Comment: You could also have an onEnter event handler on the route, or a fetch on componentWillMount fetch the data and have a spinner while the form data is fetched instead of freezing the navigation. That's a very common use for Redux Thunk

Comment: That seems like the idea I'm after :-) make that an answer?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan ok cool, that's a pattern that's very common and something I've done a lot so I'll write up an example for you now

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan I added a pretty detailed example of the whole flow of logic through action creators, reducers, and the component. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Any solution for React Router v4?

Answer (score 6):

I made a handy hook for this purpose, works with react-router v5:

```js
/*
 * Return truthy if you wish to block. Empty return or false will not block
 */
export const useBlock = func => {
    const { block, push, location } = useHistory()
    const lastLocation = useRef()

    const funcRef = useRef()
    funcRef.current = func

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location === lastLocation.current || !funcRef.current)
            return
        lastLocation.current = location

        const unblock = block((location, action) => {
            const doBlock = async () => {
                if (!(await funcRef.current(location, action))) {
                    unblock()
                    push(location)
                }
            }
            doBlock()
            return false
        })
    }, [location, block, push])
}
```

Inside your component, use it like:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    useBlock(async location => await fetchShouldBlock(location))

    return <span>Hello</span>
}
```

Navigation will not occur until the async function returns; you can completely block the navigation by returning `true`.

Comment: It’s nice to see new answers with modern code on question with outdated answers.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

**First and foremost**, I want to say that there [is a debate around](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1389) the topic of fetching data with react-router's `onEnter` hooks whether or not is good practice, nevertheless this is how something like that would go:

You can pass the redux-store to your `Router`. Let the following be your Root component, where `Router` is mounted:

```
...
import routes from 'routes-location';

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          { routes(store) }
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
...
```

And your routes will be something like:

```
import ...
...

const fetchData = (store) => {
  return (nextState, transition, callback) => {
    const { dispatch, getState } = store;
    const { loaded } = getState().myCoolReduxStore;
    // loaded is a key from my store that I put true when data has loaded

    if (!loaded) {
      // no data, dispatch action to get it
      dispatch(getDataAction())
        .then((data) => {
          callback();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // maybe it failed because of 403 forbitten, we can use tranition to redirect.
          // what's in state will come as props to the component `/forbitten` will mount.
          transition({
            pathname: '/forbitten',
            state: { error: error }
          });
          callback();
        });
    } else {
      // we already have the data loaded, let router continue its transition to the route
      callback();
    }
  }
};

export default (store) => {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="myPage" name="My Page" component={MyPage} onEnter={fetchData(store)} />
      <Route path="forbitten" name="403" component={PageForbitten} />
      <Route path="*" name="404" component={PageNotFound} />
    </Route>
  );
};
```

Please notice that your router file is exporting a thunk with your store as argument, if you look upwards, see how we invoked the router, we pass the store object to it.

Sadly, at the time of writing [react-router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md) return 404 to me, thus I cannot point you to the docs where `(nextState, transition, callback)` are described. But, about those, from my memory:

- `nextState` describes the route `react-router` will transition to;
- `transition` function to preform maybe another transition than the one from `nextState`;
- `callback` will trigger your route transition to finish.

Another think to point out is that with redux-thunk, your dispatch action can return a promise, check it in the docs [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition). You can find [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1676) a good example on how to configure your redux store with redux-thunk.

Comment: It should be noted that the "debate" you mention is now very outdated and has never been resolved, see [this issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7783) for a clarifying statement.