# How to set a timeout for executed onClick function of react-router Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, timeout

Suppose there is a react-router Link component.

```
class MyLink extends Component {
  handleOnClick = () => {
    doSomething();
    // Expecting to have a timeout before routing to another route
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <StyledLink
          to="/stock"
          onClick={this.handleOnClick}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

How to set a timeout after onClick event before routing the history path?

**EDIT**

I have reposted [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51856060/9768260) with a complete use case and solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Router: how to wait for an async action before route transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849933/react-router-how-to-wait-for-an-async-action-before-route-transition)

Comment: Could easily use the setTimeOut() method for resolving this?

Comment: Do you want to redirect immediately after doSomething() finishes execution? or do you want to redirect after a given number of seconds? Your link to the other issue is broken, please fix.

Comment: @yuanlai remember to mark the answer that was most helpful to you as the correct answer. If your issue has not been resolved please add comments to the answers or here so the community can help you

Comment: The problem is easily solved by setTimeout, this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004819/withrouter-can-not-work-in-componentdidupdate. Thanks again for nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do and what doSomething() does.

If your doSomething() function is **not async**:

```
handleOnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent transition
    doSomething();

    // redirect after 1 second
    window.setTimeout(() => {
       this.props.history.push(this.props.match.path);
    }, 1000)
};
```

If doSomething() is **async**, then you can wait for it to finish and then redirect:

```
handleOnClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent transition
    await doSomething(); // wait until it finishes

    // redirect
    this.props.history.push(this.props.match.path);
};
```

or combine **both**:

```
handleOnClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent transition
    await doSomething(); // wait until it finishes

    // redirect 1 second after doSomething() finishes.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
       this.props.history.push(this.props.match.path);
    }, 1000)
};
```

Remember to handle any errors if the function is async.

*this.props.match.path* will get the path in the "to" property of Link.

Also, don't forget to use withRouter in your component.

Version:

```
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could preventing the link from navigating app but you gonna navigate it later programmatically afterwards:

```
handleOnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent transition
    doSomething();

    // and after timeout
    window.setTimeout(() => {
       this.props.history.push('/stock')
       // history is available by design in this.props when using react-router
    }, 3000) // 3000 means 3 seconds
};
```

Comment: How to set the timeout instantly after doSomething() method?

Comment: I have tried this solution, this timeout set before doSomething method. Seem like my doSomething is a reducer method.

Comment: Add `doSomthing()` code to see if I'm able to help you.

Comment: if doSomething() is async and it takes more than 3 seconds, this will push before the action is completed.