# WithRouter can not work in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The brief code like this.

```
componentDidUpdate(preProps) {
  if ( preProps.somethingFeedback === 'whatINeed') {
    this.props.feedbackReducer()
    this.props.toggleExitAnimation()
    this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push('path')
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Firstly I use feedback reducer to update current component's props. In componentDidUpdate method I catch this props, conditionally to dispatch another two reducers. Because of the toggling animation, I also need a timeout before routing.

The component is wrapped with react-redux's connect nested in react-router's withRouter hoc function.

I find the original code, feedbackReducer function will cause automatically to route. if I comment feedbackReducer function, the this.props.history.push will not work.

**EDIT**

The problem is solved by the code below.

```
componentDidUpdate(preProps) {
  if ( preProps.somethingFeedback === 'whatINeed') {
    this.props.toggleExitAnimation()
    this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.feedbackReducer()
      this.props.history.push('path')
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

For my careless, the feedbackReducer have a key feedback to trigger the routing, so it should timeout together with history.push.

Comment: Have you checked if `this.props.history` is available inside the timeout function?

Comment: I add the console.log in timeout function, the original code can not log a message but can be routed. In contrast If I comment feedbackReducer.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.props.history);` inside the timeout function?

Comment: The history show the correct path, the route component is still not changed.

Comment: how do you use withRouter Hoc in export statement ?

Comment: Okay, I'm a little bit confused... Just to be clear: the code is working if you comment out `this.props.feedbackReducer()` ?
If so, what does `this.props.feedbackReducer()` do?
Can you post the code of the feedbackReducer function?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this point, the feedbackReducer have a key route feedback, if it comments, the routing can not work. The code should timeout the feedbackReducer with history.push together.