# Prevent going back conditionally with react-router-dom 5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(_ => {
        console.log(history.action);
        if (history.action === 'POP' && (location.pathname === Settings_NewPersonPath || location.pathname === Settings_NewBusinessPath) && entityState.data) {
            setEntityState({
                ...entityState,
                submitted: false
            });
        }
    })
}, [])
```

I'm emulating having multiple pages using a state. However, when someone is on the second "page", and they press the back button, **I just want to update the state and not actually go back.**

How would I do this?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659233/1751640) answer of mine.

Comment: @AliBdeir do you want to stop the transition to Settings_NewPersonPath and Settings_NewBusinessPath routes, o do you want to save the data first and then apply the route change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Route Context` to handle the routes changes and create listeners for those components where you need to save the data before changing the route or prevent the route changes:

**RouteProvider.js**

Add this component to the top of your component structure, but inside the `Router` component.

```
const RouteContext = React.createContext();

const RouteProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const locationKey = useRef({ /* keep tracking the route history */
    to: null,
    from: null,
  });
  const listeners = useRef({});
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    /* set the locationKey value during the first render*/
    locationKey.current = {
      from: history.location.pathname,
      to: history.location.pathname
    }
    return history.block(({ pathname }, action) => {
      if(locationKey.current.to === pathname) return;
      if (locationKey.current.from === pathname) {
        /** you are going to the last route visited */
        const listenerValues = Object.values(listeners.current);
        listenerValues.forEach(({callback, prevent}) => {
          callback();
        });
        /** if one listener needs to prevent the route changes */
        if(listenerValues.find(({prevent})=> prevent)) return false;
      }
      locationKey.current = { from: locationKey.current.to, to: pathname };    
    });
  }, [history]);

  /* add listeners*/
  const onBackListener = (callback, prevent = false) => {
    const ID = Date.now;
    listeners.current[ID] = {
      callback,
      prevent,
    };
    return ID;
  };

  /* remove listeners*/
  const removeListener = (ID) => delete listeners.current[ID] ;

  return <RouteContext.Provider value={{onBackListener, removeListener}}>{children}</RouteContext.Provider>;
};
```

**SecondComponent.js**

This component will add a listener to the RouteContext and will prevent the route changes.

```
function Second() {
  const {onBackListener, removeListener} = React.useContext(RouteContext);
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(()=> {
     const listener = onBackListener(()=> {
       /**save data */
       console.log("saving data");
       setState("Data")
     }, true);


     return () => removeListener(listener);
  }, []);

  return <h2>Second Page</h2>;
}
```

I didn't test all possibles escenarios but it will give you an idea of how to transform this to accomplish your requirements.

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twwmiw) If you try to go from Second component to the Home component the data is saved and the route doesn't changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`history.block`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/blocking-transitions.md) API to prevent page transition. Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unblock = history.block(({ action, location, retry }) => {
    // Conditional state manipulation
    // Call unblock and retry to actually perform transition
  });

  return () => {
    unblock();
  };
}, []);
```